# c# InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net

I try to use this code :

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", "user");
```

It work great but not when i use it in a new thread. I get an InvalidCastException. What can I do ?

Comment: Please post the full text of the exception message you get.

Comment: "but not when i use it in a new thread". Maybe the code needs to be executed on the UI thread? But that shouldn't throw a InvalidCastException...

Comment: An additional question would be 'why are you using a separate thread?'.  Why can't this work be done in the main thread?  This would reduce your number of threads as well as simplify your problem.

Comment: if i use the code in the main thread, it hangs up

Comment: @dtb, Although the exception doesn't relate to calling non-reentrant code in a separate thread, the call may be breaking the internal state of the object so its internal code does an invalid cast.

Answer (score 0):

`webBrowser` must be a GUI element, and most GUI elements do not handle multi-threading well.  You should typically only access GUI objects on the main UI thread of the application.

The easiest way to delegate calls to the UI thread is to use [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx).

Comment: ok thanks but im a beginner, can u give me an example with webbrowser ?

Comment: @leppie: I almost said that, but then I saw Dispatcher is in WindowsBase.dll not PresentationFramework.dll like all the other WPF stuff.

Comment: We haven't been told what type `webBrowser` is.  If it's a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, you can just use its `Invoke` or better yet `BeginInvoke` method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
delegate void ActionExecutorOnUI(ref HtmlElement a, string b, string c);
private void SetValueOnHtmlElementOnUIThread(this HtmlElement onElement, string propToChange, string valueGiven, WebBrowser linkToWebBrowser)
        {
            if (linkToWebBrowser.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ActionExecutorOnUI d = new ActionExecutorOnUI(SetValueOnHtmlElementOnUIThread);
                linkToWebBrowser.Invoke(d, new object[] { });
            }
            else
                SetValueOnHtmlElementOnUIThread(ref onElement, propToChange, valueGiven);

        }

private void SetValueOnHtmlElementOnUIThread(ref HtmlElement onElement, string propToChange, string valueGiven)
        {
            onElement.SetAttribute("value", "user"); 
        }
```