# InvalidCastException when trying to automate WebBrowser C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, browser, autoresetevent

Basically I'm automating a site that has an iframe and doesn't fire DocumentComplete. I'm running a Form in an independant thread, which contains a WebBrowser. I'm trying to click search within the WebBrowser, it works normally but I'm trying to separate the Browser from the form thread-wise so I can make my code overall more procedural and implement an AutoResetEvent.

Here's the method for Clicking search:

```
    public void ClickSearch()
    {
        if (search == null)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection links = Document.Window.Frames[0].Frames[1].Document.Links;
            search = links.Cast<HtmlElement>()
                 .Where(x => x != null)
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.InnerText == "Search");
        }
        Doc.InvokeScript("htmlbSL", new object[]{search, 2, search.Id+":SEARCH", '0'});
    }
```

Here's the code that calls it:

```
            var evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            HtmlElementEventHandler handler = null;
            handler = new HtmlElementEventHandler(
                delegate(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs ev)
            {
                ev.BubbleEvent = false;
                smsBrowser.Doc.Focusing -= handler;

                worklist = new Worklist();
                worklist.Load(smsBrowser.GetWorklistCsv());

                SQLiteDatabase.InsertWorklist(worklist);
                SQLiteDatabase.Commit();
                SQLiteDatabase.FillWorklistGrid();

                evt.Set();
            });

            smsBrowser.Doc.Focusing += handler;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => smsBrowser.ClickSearch());

            evt.WaitOne();
```

The line:

```
HtmlElementCollection links = Document.Window.Frames[0].Frames[1].Document.Links;
```

is giving me an InvalidCastException. Also, any advice as to how to best do this would be much appreciated, I want to avoid Application.DoEvents(), I also want it to be more procedure (I have many events attaching and detaching). The calling method is also running within an event handler, I'd like to put them within the same method with implemented waits to clean up my code.

I followed this guide earlier: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx.

Here are the exception details, though they don't provide much help.

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: Do you have the exception details? It usually points you exactly what's the problem... On a side note: try asking 1 question at a time if you want to get answer. Some ppl are good with web-browser, some with multithreading.. harder to find ppl good with both..

Comment: I provided the exception details. They do not help at all... I'm not casting. The problem is with the threading, and trying to execute ClickSearch asynchronously. This could works synchronously but locks the browser.

Comment: I'm not a pro, but GUI elements rarely like multithreading.. Delegates should do it. See : [c sharp system invalidcastexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268281/c-sharp-system-invalidcastexception) or [c sharp invalidcastexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064048/c-sharp-invalidcastexception)

Comment: That solved the problem with InvalidCastException. The issue is now using AutoResetEvent with the webbrowser. I'm no expert either but I believe the Browser and Form code lock because they're on the same messaging loop. So the code locks at evt.WaitOne();, the ClickSearch() method fires but essentially the event never fires.